# How to InvokeRESTAPI@1 for Azure DevOps own REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I want to use the [InvokeRESTAPI@1 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/invoke-rest-api-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in an Azure DevOps to query the Azure DevOps API itself (in the same org, same project). That should be able to use the built-in Azure pipeline token and not require a separate serviceConnection. However I only ever directly get `Nothing to show. Final logs are missing. This can happen when the job is cancelled or times out.`. So I assume some settings are wrong.

This is how my tasks looks like (with some dummy api call I tested with curl).

```
- task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
  displayName: Check builds
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
    method: 'GET'
    urlSuffix: '/myorg/myproject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0'
    headers: |
      {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

Comment: you can use the built-in Azure pipeline token and do not require a separate serviceConnection. In the connectionType input, select Azure Pipelines. In the urlSuffix input, use the appropriate API endpoint for your needs
-   [Invoke Azure Function / REST API checks - Asynchronous checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/invoke-checks?view=azure-devops#asynchronous-checks)
-   [Invoke Azure Function / REST API checks - Synchronous checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/invoke-checks?view=azure-devops#synchronous-checks)

Comment: Example, to get a list of builds, you can use /$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I don't have an Azure Function as I just want to do some sanitary checks on my pipeline parameters via the ADO API. `Azure Pipelines` doesn't seem to be a valid input for `connectionType`, the doc lists only `connectedServiceName` | `connectedServiceNameARM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the **`InvokeRESTAPI`** task in pipeline to call the Azure DevOps REST API:

1. **`use the built-in Azure pipeline token`** ✔️

   Correct, you can use the built-in [**`System.AccessToken`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) to access the access the resources within the same organization.
2. **`not require a separate serviceConnection`** ✖️

   No, a [**Generic service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#generic-service-connection) is required even if the resources are within the same organization or same project. See [**Inputs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/invoke-rest-api-v1?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml#inputs) of the **`InvokeRESTAPI`** task.

---

For your case, to use the **`InvokeRESTAPI`** task to call the Azure DevOps REST API to query builds within the same organization, you can do like as below:

1. At first, go to "**Project Settings**" > "**Service connections**", set up a new **Generic service connection** like as below image showing. The value of "**`Server URL`**" should be the prefix of the HTTP URI of the API. It should contain the prefix "**`https://dev.azure.com`**" at least.

   [image]
2. Then go to the pipeline to configure the **`InvokeRESTAPI`** task like as below.

   - To use the built-in **`System.AccessToken`** to call the API, you can set the headers like as below.

     ```json
     {
       . . .
       "Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
     }
     ```
   - The value of **`urlSuffix`** should be the rest part of the HTTP URI of the API that does not contain the prefix set on the **Generic service connection**. Ensure the prefix and the **`urlSuffix`** can combine to be the complete HTTP URI of the API, no characters are less or extra.

     For example:

     The complete HTTP URI is,

     ```
     https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0
     ```

     If the prefix set on the **Generic service connection** is,

     ```
     https://dev.azure.com
     ```

     Then, the **`urlSuffix`** should be,

     ```
     /{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0
     ```

Below is an example as reference.

```yaml
  jobs:
  - job: Agentless
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
      displayName: 'Invoke REST API'
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
        serviceConnection: 'AdoGeneric'
        method: 'GET'
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
          }
        urlSuffix: '/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0'
        waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

---

Comment: This worked, thanks for the detailed answer! I didn't know I could generate a service connection without token etc.

Comment: Sure! I just hadn't found the right button previously o.O